# Difference between Object and Bundle class

Tags: java

I am beginner of Java. Please help me what is difference between Object and Bundle class? I am searching but can not understand.

Comment: In what context? What research have you done? Stack overflow is not a replacement for documentation.

Comment: And I repeat from there that there is no `Bundle` class in the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that [Bundle extends Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). However there is no Bundle class in JDK. The best I can get is the [ResourceBundleClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html) in JDK.

Whereas The Object([in the API reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)) class sits at the top of the class hierarchy tree in the Java development environment. Every class in the Java system is a descendent (direct or indirect) of the Object class.